# workfront api output to csv

Tags: python, workfront-api

I would like to convert each workfront api object (Projects, Isues, Tasks, etc) output to a csv using Python.  Is there a recommended way to do this with the nested objects?  For example: json to csv, list to csv, etc?

Thanks,

Victor

Answer (score 0):

Parsing nested objects is a challenge with Python. I would suggest opting for multiple CSVs for each set of objects referenced in the collection of another object (tasks contained in a project, for example). Ensure that you have a key that can be used to link entries between the files, such as the tasks' project ID.